# Gotta catch anteriors elements with parents

Tags: jquery, parents

My html:

```
<dl class="last">
    <dt><label>Medidas</label></dt>
    <dd class="last">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" class="input-text  product-custom-option" id="options_22_text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I have the id options_22_text as reference, I need to add a class on the dl.

Can someone help me?

I wish the result was that:

```
<dl class="last myClass">
    <dt><label>Medidas</label></dt>
    <dd class="last">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" value="" name="options[22]" class="input-text  product-custom-option" id="options_22_text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('#options_22_text').closest('dl').addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

should work:

```
$('#options_22_text').parents('dl.last').addClass('myClass');
```

If the above doesnt work remove the `dl` and keep only `.last` (the class name).

Take into consideration if this is a nested that means that there will be more `last` classes all of them will be found. in which case you can do:

```
$('#options_22_text').closest('dl').addClass('myClass');

// or if you want something a bit faster / more specific 

$('#options_22_text').parent().parent().parent().addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the ancestor tag `dl`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfxuK/)**

```
$('#options_22_text').closest('dl').addClass('myClass');
```